# Determine whether the series sin^2(1/n) converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Determine whether the series sin^2(1/n) converges or diverges.

Having real trouble with this one, I know all the terms are positive because it is being squared but I don't know where to begin with showing whether it converges or diverges. From playing with a calculator it seems like the terms are getting smaller so im assuming it converges, any pointers that would help out would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Is this the sequence or the series?  In fact, both converge.  The sequence obviously converges to $0$.

The series converges by direct comparison.  Since $|\sin{x}| \leq x$ for all $x > 0$ (prove this!), it follows that $\sum{\sin^2({\frac{1}{n}})} \leq \sum{\frac{1}{n^2}} < \infty$

Comment: Ok thanks, I can see how |sin x| <= x leads to the desired result. I have no idea how to prove it though, I can see its true through geometric reasoning but I haven't a clue as to where to begin by proving it normally.

Comment: Try using the derivative: $sinx-x \geq 0$, then $cosx-1 \geq 0$....